# The startup disk does not have enough space to be partitioned

Tags: windows, catalina, bootcamp, partition, error

I know there's many threads on this but the many many solutions I have tried are not working for me.
I'm hoping I can get a customised response to whatever is causing my issue.
I had bootcamp Windows before but (now regrettably) removed it.
I've added my diskutil list
I'd super-appreciate and assistance
thanks!
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you give the result of command ``tmutil listlocalsnapshots /``

Comment: thanks for your reply, I added above, I don't know how to add pic in comment.

Comment: OK, there are no snapshots. You can try boot your Mac in Safe mode then reboot and retry BootCamp utility.

Comment: Ok I have done that, same error as before

Comment: You can try shrink manually your system container to 429 g for test :  ``diskutil ap resizecontainer disk2 429g  jhfs+ test 0b``. If it's accepted, you can give the result of ``diskutil list ``

Comment: ok, after safe mode I think its renamed disk2 to disk1, I ran your command as disk1, it succeeded. I have put the diskutil list result above

Comment: OK. Then you erase the test partition : ``diskutil erasevolume free space disk0s3`` and increase the container disk1 with the fried space : ``diskutil ap resizecontainer disk1 0b`` then reboot the Mac and retry BootCamp.

Comment: done, to no avail I'm afraid

Comment: I have no more idea. May be you can boot in Recovery Mode and with disk utility do a SOS on the system container.

Comment: what do you mean by an SOS, the first aid option?

Comment: Can you post the output from the command `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 limits`?

Comment: I suppose if the Boot Camp Assistant states needing 42 GB then, this could be a value between 41.5 GB and 42.5 GB. The difference between the Maximum and Recommended Minimum is 42.3 GB. You probably should free up a few more gigabytes of space.

Comment: I don't really understand why,  but doing as you suggested, I freed up about another 5-10gb and bootcamp actually let me through the process! I had about 70gb once it allowed me. Anyway, thanks so much to you both for all the help.